# How to manage large MySQL databases (backup)

Tags: mysql, database, backup, innodb

We have a production MySQL database of about 320GB on disk.

We need to perform regular backups of the dataset but, either mysqldump or "copying table files" are taking hours to complete; moreover, both commands lock the database leading to an unusable website.

At the moment out tables are InnoDB and we have no replication, clustering, master&slave in place.

Is there any way we can perform daily backups without having to take down the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Have you tried `mysqldump --single-transaction`? This does not lock the database server, if you only back up InnoDB tables.

Option 2: Percona XtraBackup, but this software is not available for Windows.

Option 3: Percona XtraBackup on Windows. Read this blog that describes a way to use Docker to run Percona XtraBackup on Windows: https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/03/20/running-percona-xtrabackup-windows-docker/

Option 4: [Create a replication slave](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at XtraBackup tool

Comment: Tip: you can also combine the replication slave with mysqldump or xtrabackup. This way, you can do whatever you want on the slave without impacting performance of the master.

Answer (score 0):

And you don't have LVM in place either?  Remember the "Think Ahea..." signs?  Sorry; SOL.

And I guess you are using Windows, so you can't use Percona's XtraBackup?